# About Domain Infrastructure

Tags: active-directory, domain

I have some questions about domain infrastructure in a business.
We are one company with multiple subsidiaries all over the world.
I am in the IT department and we do not travel a lot on each site, so we sometimes use MSPs to help us, especially on 2 sites.

In our company, we currently have 3 forests :

- Forest A-1 (multiple subsidiaries)
- Forest A-2 (same name, but not the same...don't ask - 1 subsidiary)
- Forest B (1 subsidiary)

We have a trust relationship between Forest A-1 and Forest B.
The reason we have Forest B, as explained to me (I was not part of the company back then), is because we work with an MSP that requires domain admin rights. It is on an island and we do not have a choice in a matter of MSPs, they set up the network there so it was accepted.

We have a federation with Azure AD (A unique tenant) on Forest A-1 and Forest B, but we can't do it with Forest A-2 for obvious reasons.

Plus, due to the fact that Forest A-2 has the same name as Forest A-1, they cannot really communicate.
We do use an MSP's services there but they are not as restrictive as for Forest B.

So in order to solve these issue, we decided to delete Forest A-2 and restart.
There is not a lot there, 20 computers and a few servers.
I am rooting to add this site to Forest A-1 and managing the MSP's rights with local admin accounts (even on servers) and permissions on OUs, but some of my colleagues disagree because of the experience they have with the MSP on Forest B.

So they keep telling me that it will be more secure having a different forest with the MSP have domain admin rights, than handling the site with secured OUs. That could have issues with the AD replication there and they would need to intervene, and giving them domain admin rights for a limited time is not a good idea (because of the scope of the domain admin).

My intake on multiple forest is that it seems more complex to handle user permissions and policies.
It will be simpler for our team to have less forest on a daily basis.

I would like you opinion on this. Do you think it would be better to handle everything with OUs, or create a different forest and giving the MSP admin rights ?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Opinion-based questions are off-topic, however the most important part is here : `[...]because of the experience they have with the MSP[...]`. Experience is the most important thing in this kind of situation IMHO

Comment: Thank you, and I understand that, but it is the experience with only one MSP on a completely different country. How could we make decisions for the whole company base only from 1 isolated experience ?

Comment: You've explained the existing configuration and you've explained what you want to do,but you haven't actually explained the problem. What's the actual  problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am sorry about that, I wasn't clear enough. The problem is that it is impossible for Forest A-1 and A-2 to talk to each other. Plus, we are using Azure AD Connect for SSO and we had to choose only one Forest A-x for this. So we would like to make it possible for everyone to "talk" to each other and be able to set SSO for every site.